# Commutator $[A_{p,q},A_{s,t}]$ in the pure braid group?

Tags: group-theory, braid-groups

Let $B_n$ be the braid group; that is, a group generated by $\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_{n-1}$ with relations

1. $\sigma_i\sigma_{i+1}\sigma_i=\sigma_{i+1}\sigma_i\sigma_{i+1}$ for $i=1,\cdots,n-2$;
2. $\sigma_i\sigma_j=\sigma_j\sigma_i$ if $i,j\in\{1,\cdots,n-1\}$ and $|i-j|\geq 2$.

For $1\leq i<j\leq n$, let the usual generator $A_{i,j}$ of pure braid groups be defined as $$A_{i,j}=(\sigma_{j-1}\sigma_{j-2}\cdots\sigma_{i+1})\sigma_i^2(\sigma_{i+1}^{-1}\cdots\sigma_{j-2}^{-1}\sigma_{j-1}^{-1}).$$

> **My question**: Is there a formula for the commutator
>   $[A_{p,q},A_{s,t}]$?

By the way, I found the following related result in *Artin braid groups and the homotopy groups* by J. Li and J. Wu:

[image]

Comment: Nobody appears to be biting.  Have you thought about moving this to MO?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Well, thank you for offing the bounty for this question. The question is related to one of my research problems and that's why I asked. But now I managed to solve my problem without knowing $[A_{p,q},A_{s,t}]$ and thus I am not that interested in this question itself. But you can go ahead to post the same question at MO, if you are interested.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber, my guess is that the answer might look extremely complicated and it is not surprising that there are dozens of cases to consider.